# set lwd of axis in par() function

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot with a certain line width (about 1/5 of default `lwd`). All lines in the plot should have this `lwd`.

I do:

```
par(lwd = 0.2)
plot(1:10, type = "l")
```

The result is ok except for the thickness of the axes lines and ticks, which seems to be unaffected by the `par()` function.

The only option I know is to separately define the lwd for each axis:

```
par(lwd = 0.2)
plot(1:10, type = "l", axes = F)
axis(1, lwd = 0.2)
axis(2, lwd = 0.2)
box()
```

[image: plot without and with separate lwd setting for axis]

However, this is tedious and I can not imagine that there is no "global" `lwd` option. If you have an idea how this could be done efficiently for several plots please respond.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think what you're looking for exists. I have a hunch that individual `axis()` calls is the way to do this in base graphics.

Comment: Why not make your workaround a function so that you can make several such figures easily?

Comment: I am looking exactly for this, thanks for this question! It is a shame there's no global lwd setting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the formals of `axis()` function - default `lwd` is specified as 1:

```
> axis
function (side, at = NULL, labels = TRUE, tick = TRUE, line = NA,
    pos = NA, outer = FALSE, font = NA, lty = "solid", lwd = 1,
    lwd.ticks = lwd, col = NULL, col.ticks = NULL, hadj = NA,
    padj = NA, ...)
{
```

And as you noticed they are not affected by the `par()` setting in this implementation.

One simple solution would be to make a wrapper for `axis()` function and make it use the `par()` setting by default. Here is how that might look like:

```
axislwd <- function(...) axis(lwd=par()$lwd, ...)

par(lwd = 0.2)
plot(1:10, type = "l", axes = F)
axislwd(1)
axislwd(2)
box()
```

Alternatively you can write a wrapper for the whole plot function instead:

```
plotlwd <- function(...) {
  plot(axes = FALSE, ...)
  axis(1, lwd=par()$lwd)
  axis(2, lwd=par()$lwd)
  box()
}

par(lwd = 0.2)
plotlwd(1:10, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, saves already some typing. Is it also possible to do a wrapper of the `plot()` function which include an argument `lwd.axis = 0.2`? I did not yet find a way to do it within the plot function.

Comment: @retodomax added a second solution with the `plot()` wrapper.